# The convergence of a bounded sequence ${x_n}$ satisfying $x_{n+1} - \epsilon_n \le x_n$, where $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \epsilon_n$ is absolutely convergent

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, cauchy-sequences

Statement: If a bounded sequence $\{x_n\}_{n=0}^\infty$ in $\mathbb{R}$ satisfies $x_{n+1} - \epsilon_n \le x_n$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$, where $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \epsilon_n$ is an absolute convergent series, then $\{x_n\}_{n=0}^\infty$ is convergent.

I think the statement is true and there are two cases:

(1) There are finitely many positive $\epsilon_n$'s.

Then $\exists N\in \mathbb{N}$ s.t. $x_{n+1} - x_n \le \epsilon_n \lt 0 
\; \forall n \ge N$. So $\{x_n\}_{n=0}^\infty$ is decreasing when $n \ge N$. Since it is bounded, it converges.

(2) There are infinitely many positive $\epsilon_n$'s.

This is where I am stuck. I think since $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \epsilon_n$ is absolutely convergent, $\epsilon_n$ converges to $0$. But how to proceed?

Any hint would be appreciated!

Comment: Then $x_n$ converges and $\epsilon_n$'s are all non-negative. Does this lead to any contradiction?

Comment: We know that $|\epsilon_n|$ converges to $0$, so we must have $|x_n-x_{n+1}|<\epsilon$ for $n\geq N$.

Comment: The sequence must have a real $\liminf_n{x_n}$ , you can start from here.

Comment: @高田航 $x_n-x_{n+1}$ could be a large positive number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $S_n= \epsilon_1+\epsilon_2+...+\epsilon_{n-1}$. Then, $S_n$ is convergent, and hence  also bounded.

Define $y_n=x_n-S_n$. Then, $y_n$ is the difference of two bounded sequences and hence bounded. Moreover,

$$y_{n+1}-y_n=x_{n+1}-x_n -(S_{n+1}-S_n)=x_{n+1}-x_n-\epsilon_n \leq 0$$

This shows that $y_n$ is monotonic.

Therefore, $y_n$ is monotonic and bounded, and hence convergent.

It follows that $x_n=y_n+S_n$ is the sum of two convergent sequences, thus convergent.

Comment: So $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \epsilon_n$ only needs to be convergent, not necessarily absolutely convergent?

Comment: @HanTang Yes, it seems so.

Comment: Ok, it's clear now.